# Calculate each user's overall login period in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, authentication, logout

I am calculating each user's overall duration in the webform. I have the user's login and logout time stored in the database already. But anyone have ideas on how to do the calculations? I am using ASP.NET C#

Comment: Running an Query against your Database?

Comment: Substract the start from the finish

Comment: Or in C#, Timespan timespan = logoutTime- loginTime;

Comment: what type of  duration do you want to return ? minute or hour or day?

Comment: I noticed your account hasn't accepted any answers for your question.  Could you please accept my answer here and also accept other answers as appropriate for your other questions?

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is deduct your end time from your start time for each record then sum the result.  I'm going to let you figure out how to get data from your database since it varies wildly depending on your setup.

So lets say you're reading your database into a class with DateTimes for Login and Logout.  And lets assume you've already read them into memory so now we have a list of the relevant login periods.

```
var totalTime = new TimeSpan(loginPeriods.Select(x => x.Logout - x.Login).Sum(x => x.Ticks));
```

What we've done here is find the amount of time between Logout and Login.  Then created a new TimeSpan object equal to that amount of time.  We did this because TimeSpan has a useful property, TotalHours.

Finally, you're using ASP.NET so we'll need to turn this into text at some point for it to be printed onto the page.

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", totalTime.TotalHours);//Returns something like 1,201
```

**Edit:** Being myself I couldn't leave this alone.  I was bothered by the lack of IEnumerable< TimeSpan >.Sum() in .Net.  So I made my own really quick.

```
public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timespans) =>
        new TimeSpan(timespans.Sum(x => x.Ticks));
```

So with this in a referenced name space you could tackle the above problem a little more elegantly.

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", loginPeriods.Select(x => x.Logout - x.Login).Sum().TotalHours)
```